# Is the error: "make: *** No rule to make target `SpecProj_scd.mk'. Stop." causing my app to crash?

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, makefile

My 1st clean & build gives this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `SpecProj_scd.mk'.  Stop.
```

Building a second time, the error is removed. *Note that ndk-build, builds fine.*

So I run the project on my actual device, a Tablet, and the app crashes.

### LogCat:

```
01-29 16:48:48.081: E/Trace(3766): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-29 16:48:48.081: D/jdwp(3766): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x39
01-29 16:48:48.110: D/dalvikvm(3766): open_cached_dex_file : /data/app/com.dece.specproj-2.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.dece.specproj-2.apk@classes.dex
01-29 16:48:48.117: D/ActivityThread(3766): BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{42436e88 com.dece.specproj}}
01-29 16:48:48.128: W/dalvikvm(3766): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/dece/specproj/MainActivity;
01-29 16:48:48.128: W/dalvikvm(3766): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/dece/specproj/MainActivity;)
01-29 16:48:48.128: D/AndroidRuntime(3766): Shutting down VM
01-29 16:48:48.128: W/dalvikvm(3766): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e17908)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load hellojni: findLibrary returned null
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at com.dece.specproj.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:13)
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     ... 15 more
```

So I made sure and that all my directories were correctly added to the Environment Variables PATH, as well as the PATH in Eclipse, i.e. my MinGW bin, MinGW msys bin, cygwin bin, android-ndk, as well as android-sdk...and I think they are all added correctly, so the error still comes up.

I'm not sure what is causing these issues as I am new to Android NDK, so I will post what I think may play a part in this.

### Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := SpecProj
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellojni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

### hellojni.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring Java_com_dece_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

### MainActivity

```
package com.dece.specproj;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public native String stringFromJNI();
      static
      {
         System.loadLibrary("hellojni");
          }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

### activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dece.specproj.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dece.specproj"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the problem is this:

```
01-29 16:48:48.137: E/AndroidRuntime(3766): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load hellojni: findLibrary returned null
```

It is unable to find a library called `libhellojni.so` (which you try to load in your java file with `System.loadLibrary("hellojni");`. Your shared library name is set in `Android.mk` in this line: `LOCAL_MODULE := SpecProj` (resulting in a file named `libSpecProj.so`).

To make things work, change the line in the java file to `System.loadLibrary("SpecProj");`.

I don't see where the error quoted in the question title would be coming from, but it is at least not directly linked to the error you're seeing at runtime. It may indicate that something else is weirdly set up in your project build (but nothing of what you quoted in the code snippets indicate that, so it would be things outside of that).

Comment: Thanks man. And I very much appreciate the time you took to go through everything. It's true that he "make" error is still there, but once you build twice it goes away...I'll just leave that error alone for now...hopefully it doesn't come back to haunt me!